# Can I save a previous item conditionally in a forEach loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make sort of sliding carousel that shows a different slide based on what the user has its mouse over. I am working with z-index to show the correct slide on top. But important is that the previous slide is underneath. So the idea is:

1. All slides `z-index: 1` by default
2. If slide is shown, set `z-index: 3`
3. When another slide is shown, set previous slide to `z-index: 2` and the new one to `3`

This was my work so far

```js
slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
navItems = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-navigation li');

navItems.forEach(navItem => {
  navItem.addEventListener('mouseover', () => onNavigationHover(navItem));
});

function onNavigationHover(navItem) {
  let slideKey = navItem.dataset.slide;

  slides.forEach((slide, index) => {
    if (slide.dataset.slide === slideKey) {
      slide.style.setProperty('--z-index', 3)
      // can i set the previous slide zIndex here to 2? 
      slide.classList.add('slideIn')
    } else {
      slide.style.setProperty('--z-index', 1)
      slide.classList.remove('slideIn')
    }
  });
}
```

```css
img {
  z-index: var(--z-index);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

img.slideIn {
  animation: slideIn 2s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  from {
    translate: 200px;
  }
  to {
    translate: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class='slider-navigation'>
  <li data-slide='1'>Slide 1</li>
  <li data-slide='2'>Slide 2</li>
  <li data-slide='3'>Slide 3</li>
</ul>

<div>
  <img class='slide' data-slide='1' src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1669818319938-bb7029dc3fa3?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwzfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60'>

  <img class='slide' data-slide='2' src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1669623313981-6af02eedb15c?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw1fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60'>

  <img class='slide' data-slide='3' src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1446776811953-b23d57bd21aa?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTF8fHNwYWNlfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60' />
</div>
```

This is working great, except that the same image will always show underneath.

Is it possible to save the previous index and give it a different z-index? Or should I approach this in a different way? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is using the `.filter()` method. You can use `.filter()` to find the current slide (*by comparing the data attribute for **slide***) as well as grab the previous slide (*by looking for any slide that has a `z-index` of 3 prior to any changes*).

The steps for your `onNavigationHover()` function would then be:

- Grab the previous top slide
- Set the `z-index` of all slides to 1
- Set the previous top slide (*if it exists, as initially it won't*) to a `z-index` of 2
- Set the new top slide to a `z-index` of 3

```js
slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
navItems = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-navigation li');

navItems.forEach(navItem => {
  navItem.addEventListener('mouseover', () => onNavigationHover(navItem));
});

function onNavigationHover(navItem) {
  let prevSlide = Array.from(slides).filter(slide => getComputedStyle(slide).zIndex == 3)[0]
  
  slides.forEach(slide => {
    slide.style.setProperty('--z-index', 1)
    slide.classList.toggle('slideIn', slide.dataset.slide == navItem.dataset.slide)
  })
  prevSlide?.style.setProperty('--z-index', 2)
  Array.from(slides).filter(slide => slide.dataset.slide == navItem.dataset.slide)[0]?.style.setProperty('--z-index', 3)
}
```

```css
img {
  z-index: var(--z-index);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

img.slideIn {
  animation: slideIn 2s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  from {
    translate: 200px;
  }
  to {
    translate: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class='slide' data-slide='1' width=200 src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1669818319938-bb7029dc3fa3?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwzfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60'>

  <img class='slide' data-slide='2' width=200 src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1669623313981-6af02eedb15c?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw1fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60'>
  
  <img class='slide' data-slide='3' width=200 src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1446776811953-b23d57bd21aa?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTF8fHNwYWNlfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60' />
</div>

<ul class='slider-navigation'>
  <li data-slide='1'>Slide 1</li>
  <li data-slide='2'>Slide 2</li>
  <li data-slide='3'>Slide 3</li>
</ul>
```

### Edit/Update

A comment from OP noted my answer doesn't address "*saving the previous item outside the forEach loop in a variable*". The example above does actually store the previous slide in a variable called `prevSlide`, however this variable is not global (*which is an easy fix by just declaring the variable outside of the `onNavigationHover()` function instead*).

But I wanted to add some additional info because it looks like this may be a sort of [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where the desired method of solving the problem isn't necessarily how it needs to be solved. While my snippet above does save the previous slide in a variable, *it doesn't need to*. Even if the previous slide needs to be accessed somewhere else in the code, the same `.filter()` logic can be applied to check the `z-index` and determine if a slide is the current active slide, the previous slide, or any other slide.

I am only adding this edit because I think many questions here on Stack Overflow get stuck in the mindset that the problem needs to be solved a certain way, which can prevent users from learning about new methods and different ways of approaching code and how they solve certain problems. But not get too far off-topic, here is yet another code snippet that doesn't save the previous slide at all but functions identically, simply because saving the previous slide *shouldn't* be necessary.

```js
const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide'),
navItems = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-navigation li')

navItems.forEach(navItem => {
  navItem.addEventListener('mouseover', () => onNavigationHover(navItem))
});

function onNavigationHover(navItem) {
  slides.forEach(slide => {
    let newIndex = (slide.dataset.slide == navItem.dataset.slide) ? 3 : (getComputedStyle(slide).zIndex == 3) ? 2 : 1
    slide.style.setProperty('--z-index', newIndex)
    slide.classList.toggle('slideIn', slide.dataset.slide == navItem.dataset.slide)
  })
}
```

```css
img {
  z-index: var(--z-index);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

img.slideIn {
  animation: slideIn 2s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  from {
    translate: 200px;
  }
  to {
    translate: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class='slide' data-slide='1' width=200 src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1669818319938-bb7029dc3fa3?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwzfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60'>

  <img class='slide' data-slide='2' width=200 src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1669623313981-6af02eedb15c?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw1fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60'>
  
  <img class='slide' data-slide='3' width=200 src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1446776811953-b23d57bd21aa?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTF8fHNwYWNlfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60' />
</div>

<ul class='slider-navigation'>
  <li data-slide='1'>Slide 1</li>
  <li data-slide='2'>Slide 2</li>
  <li data-slide='3'>Slide 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: While this might not exactly answering the question of saving the previous item outside the forEach loop in a variable, it is by far the most elegant solution to this problem and also didn't have any issues, while the other solutions did. So I marked this one as answer. Thanks for all the responses though.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use JS directly as in the other answer that uses your updated example. Or based on your original post, add an attribute or even just an id to your DOM element like so

```
function onNavigationHover(navItem) {
  let slideKey = navItem.dataset.slide;

  slides.forEach((slide, index) => {
    if (slide.dataset.slide === slideKey) {
      slide.style.setProperty('--z-index', 3)
      // Set the index of the old element
      document.getElementById('active')?.style.setPropery('--z-index', 2);
      // Remove the id of the old element
      document.getElementById('active')?.removeAttribute('id');
      // Set the id on the current element
      slide.id = 'active';
    } else {
      slide.style.setProperty('--z-index', 1)
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I wrote this, before there was an edit to the question, still, this is an excerpt of the question

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't think about saving it outside of the forEach like this, smart! Unfortunately this isn't working for my use-case, but more likely to be a z-index issue, because the variable is set correctly now.

Comment: on closer inspection, this was not an issue with the z-index. But it's because the active one is rapidly set from 2 to 1. I tried setting a setTimeout on the z-index 1 in the else statement, but it becomes very glitchy. It kind of works if you do it really slowly.

Comment: Also used `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover` but it still triggers the else very quickly and goes from 2 to 1 in a split second.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You can do it by holding the previous slide like this:

```js
const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
const navItems = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-navigation li');
const previousSlide = null;

navItems.forEach(navItem => {
  navItem.addEventListener('mouseover', () => onNavigationHover(navItem));
});

function onNavigationHover(navItem) {
  let slideKey = navItem.dataset.slide;

  slides.forEach((slide, index) => {
    if (slide.dataset.slide === slideKey) {
      slide.style.setProperty('--z-index', 3);
      if(previousSlide && previousSlide !== slide) {
        previousSlide.style.setProperty('--z-index', 2);
      }
      previousSlide = slide;
      slide.classList.add('slideIn')
    } else if(slide !== previousSlide) {
      slide.style.setProperty('--z-index', 1)
      slide.classList.remove('slideIn')
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Why are you only updating either the old slide z-index or the old previousSlide object (its an if else)?
You would  need to do update the previousSlide every time instead.

Comment: I do 3 things. 1. Update current slide z-index to 3.  2. Update previousSlide z-index to 2.  3. Update other z-indexes to 1.  Isn't that what you need ?

Comment: Sorry I'm not OP, I just read your answer and it looks like in the foreach loop, in case of it beeing the correct slide you set index 3 of current Slide but then only do either previousSlide style to inde 2 OR (since its an else) Update the previousSlide Object.

Which would mean that the PreviousSlide Object does not get updated until the if is not true anymore.

which only happens when the prevSlide is the current slide, and at the very beginning when prevSlide is still null

Comment: Sorry. my mistake. I edited my answer. Please check the new one.

Comment: Looks good that is what I meant.

Comment: @Amirhossein Thank you, but it does not appear to work on my end. When I switch back and forth, it will glitch and not set the previous correctly. Could you make the example working?